# Storing image in database with asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have this code in View:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="imageFile">Image</label>
   <input type="image" name="imageFile" class="file-loading form-control input-files" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.tif" />
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.image)
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult PostIdea(PostIdeaViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase imageFile) {
   if (ModelState.IsValid) {
      var newProject = db.Projects.Create();
      if (imageFile != null && imageFile.ContentLength > 0) {
         newProject.image = new byte[imageFile.ContentLength];
         imageFile.InputStream.Read(newProject.image, 0, imageFile.ContentLength);
      } 
   } 
}
```

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Image")]
public HttpPostedFileBase image { get; set; }
```

Everything seems right to me, yet the image received by controller is null. Is there something wrong with the code?

Edit: using enctype = "multipart/form-data" and 
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.image, new { type = "file" })
worked for me.

Comment: What did your search for "HttpPostedFileBase null" yield? What does your form code look like?

Comment: Based on your model, you view should have `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.image, new { type = "file" })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke using Html.TextBoxFor gives this exception: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. 
I couldn't resolve it so tried the other appraoch.

Comment: @CodeCaster like this: using (Html.BeginForm("PostIdea", "Student", null, FormMethod.Post))

Comment: @Resham, It needs to be `<input type="file" name="image"` and it needs to be `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` You errors is due to other issues. Remove the `HttpPostedFileBase imageFile` parameter (you model has the `HttpPostedFileBase image` so that will be bound). You need to delete `newProject.image = new byte[imageFile.ContentLength];` and use `if (model.image!= null && model.image.ContentLength > 0) {`

Comment: I'm assuming your wanting save the file as a byte array in the database? If so, your data model needs a property `byte[]` that you upload that file to. But you have not shown your data model generated by `var newProject = db.Projects.Create();`

Comment: @StephenMuecke all changes done, and still I get model.image null, even Html.TextBoxFor helper yields it null.
P.S. No exception anymore

Comment: Then there are other problems with your code you have not shown us. You are doing a standard form submit (not using any ajax)?

Comment: no, not ajax. The code was quite large so i decided to put only relevant parts. It does have a byte[] property though. i.e.
  public byte[] image { get; set; }

Comment: OK, then that part will work fine. Do you have any other form controls in the view that generate `name="image"`? (e.g. a hidden input). I suggest you comment out all other form controls except `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.image, new { type = "file" })` and test it.

Comment: It gives other exceptions.. and none of the other controls generate it. They are named as 'synopsis' and 'name'.

Comment: `@model PostIdeaViewModel @using (Html.BeginForm("PostIdea", "Student", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.image, new { type = "file" }) <input type="submit" value="Save" /> }` will work fine and if you select a file, `model.image` will not be null.

Comment: Then you should delete this question. Its of no use to anyone and other may waste their time adding answers.

Comment: Yeah I tried to delete it but couldn't as it has answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the input type "file". and add an input type "submit".

My View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestImage", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="imageFile">Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="imageFile" class="file-loading form-control input-files" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.tif" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Go !</button>
}
```

My Controller :

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestImage(Models.Answer model)
    {
        var imageFiles = Request.Files;

        if (imageFiles != null && imageFiles.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase imageFile = imageFiles[0];
            if (imageFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var image = new byte[imageFile.ContentLength];
                imageFile.InputStream.Read(image, 0, imageFile.ContentLength);
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view html should be enclosed in

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", null, FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"})) 
{
   <input type="image" name="imageFile" class="file-loading form-control input-files" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.tif" />

   <input type ="submit" value="Upload"/>
}
```

**multipart/form**-data No characters are encoded. This value is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control

Comment: is your code included in form tag with mentioned attributes

Answer (score 0):

Your form must have enctype = "multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0):

the type="image" only defines that image as the submit button and not as an input that can be send over to server.

You should use input type file for your case